# Trying to print a description of an Error (AKA ErrorType) enum

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, enums

I am using an enum that inherits from `Error` (or `ErrorType` in Swift 2) and I am trying to use it in such a way that I can catch the error and use something like `print(error.description)` to print a description of the error.

This is what my Error enum looks like:

```
enum UpdateError: Error {
    case NoResults
    case UpdateInProgress
    case NoSubredditsEnabled
    case SetWallpaperError

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .NoResults:
            return "No results were found with the current size & aspect ratio constraints."
        case .UpdateInProgress:
            return "A wallpaper update was already in progress."
        case .NoSubredditsEnabled:
            return "No subreddits are enabled."
        case .SetWallpaperError:
            return "There was an error setting the wallpaper."
        }
    }

    // One of many nested enums
    enum JsonDownloadError: Error {
        case TimedOut
        case Offline
        case Unknown

        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .TimedOut:
                return "The request for Reddit JSON data timed out."
            case .Offline:
                return "The request for Reddit JSON data failed because the network is offline."
            case .Unknown:
                return "The request for Reddit JSON data failed for an unknown reason."
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

An important thing to note is that there are a few nested enums within `UpdateError` so something like this won't work because the nested enums aren't of the `UpdateError` type themselves:

```
do {
    try functionThatThrowsUpdateError()
} catch {
    NSLog((error as! UpdateError).description)
}
```

Is there a better way of printing a description of the error without having to check every type of `UpdateError` that occurred in the catch statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define another (possibly empty) protocol, and conform your errors to it.

```
protocol DescriptiveError {
   var description : String { get }
}

// specify the DescriptiveError protocol in each enum
```

You could then pattern match against the protocol type.

```
do {
  try functionThatThrowsUpdateError()
} catch let error as DescriptiveError {
  print(error.description)
}
```